# sever 403 error on big php mysql insert query not working properly insert more than 10,000+ data

Tags: php, mysql, http-status-code-403

i have mlm website, i have created to share ROI and profit share query to distribute to my users, i have 2600+ users, i have shared hosting plan from Godaddy server, when i submit to share amount page runs about 5 minutes and then server error display, after this i checked that some of users got profit but not all users, why my server stop responding on such bigquery???
here is my php script,

```
public function group_profitshare_tree_roi() {
    // AND fk_plan_id > 0
    if ( isset( $_SESSION['p2n_user_id'] ) ) {
        $by_user_id = $_SESSION['p2n_user_id'];
    }
        $user_details = $this->db()->query( "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE active = '1' AND exchanger='0'" );
    while ( $fetch_child = $this->db()->fetch( $user_details ) ) {
     $user_id = $fetch_child['user_id'];
    $accounts = new accounts();
    $level    = 1;
    /*if ( $purchase_pkg_id == 0 ) {
        $enc       = new RapidFW\Encryption( $this->db );
        $fk_pkg_id = $enc->decode( $_GET['pkg'] );
    } else {
        $fk_pkg_id = $purchase_pkg_id;
    }

    $query_pkg_price = $this->db()->fetch_direct( "SELECT * FROM packages WHERE pkg_id = '{$fk_pkg_id}'" );
    $pkg_price       = $query_pkg_price['pkg_daily_earn'];*/
    $today = date("Y-m-d")." 00:00:00";
    //$accounts->make_transaction( 'Package Purchased', $pkg_price, $fk_user_id, "debit", 2, 0 );
    $current_package = $this->db()->fetch_direct( "SELECT SUM(amount) AS total_amount FROM transactions WHERE fk_user_id = '{$user_id}' AND trans_detail = 'Daily click Profit added' AND trans_date >='{$today}'" );
    $total_amount    = $current_package['total_amount']/2;

    do {
        $details = "Profit Share Bonus";
        //$details    = "Group Commission Tree";
        $trans_type = "debit";

        $query_pkg_com = $this->db()->fetch_direct( "SELECT * FROM pkg_commissions WHERE `level` = '{$level}' AND `type` = 0" );

        $total_commission = ( $query_pkg_com['commission'] / 100 );
        $amount = ( $total_commission * $total_amount );

        $query_tree_last_user = $this->db()->fetch_direct( "SELECT `parent_key`,`membership` FROM users WHERE user_id = '{$fk_user_id}'" );
        $fk_user_id           = $query_tree_last_user['parent_key'];

        $membership = $query_tree_last_user['membership'];
        if ( $membership > 0 ) {
            $check_ML = $membership;
            $trans_of = 4;
            if ( $level <= $check_ML ) {
                
                $accounts->make_transaction( $details, $amount, $fk_user_id, $trans_type, $trans_of, $user_id );
            }
        }
        $level ++;
    } while ( $level <= 15 & $fk_user_id != 1 );
    /*while ($fetch_tree_last_user = $this->db()->fetch($query_tree_last_user)) {

        $query_tree_last_user = $this->db()->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = '{$user_id}' AND fk_plan_id > 0");// AND fk_plan_id > 0
        echo $end_user_p_key = $fetch_tree_last_user['parent_key'], ", ";

        $this->group_tree($end_user_p_key);
    } */
    }
    echo "<script>alert('Profit Shares Added Success');</script>";
}
```

Comment: `why my server stop responding on such bigquery`...probably because there's a timeout limit on the length of time a script can run for. This is often done on shared hosting so that one account cannot be constantly using all the resources of the server. Consider re-designing your overall approach.

Comment: For example you can do this task in batches, or see if the host will allow you to run it via a cron job, or something else. Use your imagination.

Comment: 1st 403 error = forbidden. 2nd not a good practice to query your database inside loops, in your case you have 2 loops, and as you said if you have 10000 records fetched at the beginning and then you have 2/3 queries fired for each record and case with 2nd loop again quering the DB. You need to optimize this, make a bit more complex queries, to select multiple rows with 1 query, instead of "WHERE pkg_id =..." for example. 3rd at the end of your do while loop you use bitwise operator instead of logical "$level <= 15 & $fk_user_id != 1" this probably also breaks the logic you're trying to put.